# stuck at oop upload image + insert

Tags: php, mysql, image, oop, upload

sorry if my querstion is bad, my english is bad

NB : ignore the sql injection filtering

i am using insert() function that I created myself to insert to database

but i am stuck with these code

I want to upload image to ../images directory. If i insert with image included, text is inserted but image not uploaded

i think the query are not going into

```
if(!empty($gambar))
{   
    $dir="../images/";
    $tmp=$_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'];
    $namafile=time().".jpg";
    $ukuran=$_FILES['gambar']['size'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['gambar']['type'];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dir.$namafile);
        $this->perintah="insert into ".$tbl." (".$kol.",gambar) values (".$isi.",".$namafile.")";
        $q=mysql_query($this->perintah);
}
```

but to

```
else 
{
    $this->perintah="insert into ".$tbl." (".$kol.") values (".$isi.")";
    $q=mysql_query($this->perintah);
}
```

i have to declare variables

```
$gambar = $_FILES['gambar'];
```

and in form tag too

```
<form method='post' action='controller.php?act=inputsiswa' name='siswa' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

my question:

whats wrong with my code?

at this lines

```
public function insert($tbl,$kol,$isi,$gambar)
```

may i declare variable to

```
public function insert($tbl,$kol,$isi,$gambar = null)
```

or

```
public function insert($tbl,$kol,$isi,empty($gambar))
```

or what?

## All of my codes

model.php

```
public function insert($tbl,$kol,$isi,$gambar)
{
    if(!empty($gambar))
    {   
        $dir="../images/";
        $tmp=$_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'];
        $namafile=time().".jpg";
        $ukuran=$_FILES['gambar']['size'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['gambar']['type'];

        move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dir.$namafile);
            $this->perintah="insert into ".$tbl." (".$kol.",gambar) values (".$isi.",".$namafile.")";
            $q=mysql_query($this->perintah);
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->perintah="insert into ".$tbl." (".$kol.") values (".$isi.")";
        $q=mysql_query($this->perintah);
    }
    echo '<script> alert("Data Berhasil Dimasukkan!"); top.location="index.php?act='.htmlentities($_GET['act']).'";</script>';
    if(!$q)
    {
        echo "<script> alert(\"Gagal Coy !\"); top.location=\"index.php\";</script>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

controller.php

```
case "inputsiswa":
$file = $_FILES['gambar'];
$isi = "'".$_POST['nisn']."','".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['nama']."','".$_POST['tempat_lahir']."','".$_POST['tanggal_lahir']."','".$_POST['jenis_kelamin']."','".$_POST['kelas']."','".$_POST['jurusan']."','".$_POST['tipekelas']."','".$_POST['goldar']."','".$_POST['alamat']."','".$_POST['kodepos']."','".$_POST['kontak']."','".$_POST['email']."','Aktif'";
$kol = "nisn,username,password,nama,tempat_lahir,tgl_lahir,jenkel,id_kelas,id_jurusan,id_tipe_kelas,id_goldar,alamat,kode_pos,kontak,email,status";
$as->insert("tbl_siswa",$kol,$isi,$file);
```

content.php

```
<form method='post' action='controller.php?act=inputsiswa' name='siswa' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    NISN<br /><input type='text' name='nisn' class='text' required/><br />
    Username<br /><input type='text' name='username' class='text' required/><br />
    Password<br /><input type='password' name='password' class='text' required/><br />
    Ulangi Password<br /><input type='password' name='password2' class='text' required/><br />
    Nama Lengkap<br /><input type='text' name='nama' class='text' required/><br />
    Tempat Lahir<br /><input type='text' name='tempat_lahir' class='text' required/><br />
    Tanggal Lahir <br /><input type='text' name='tanggal_lahir' class='text' required/><br />
    Jenis Kelamin <br />
    <select name ='jenkel'>
        <option value=''>pilih jenis kelamin..</option>
        <option value='Pria'>Pria</option>
        <option value='Wanita'>Wanita</option>
    </select> 
    <br>
    Kelas<br>
    <select name='kelas'>
    <option value ='0'>pilih kelas..</option>";
    $tbl='tbl_kelas';
    $isi = $as->select($tbl,'*');
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($isi)){
    echo"<option value=$r[id_kelas]>$r[kelas]</option>";
    }
    echo"</select><br />        

    Jurusan<br>
    <select name='jurusan'>
    <option value ='0'>pilih jurusan..</option>";
    $tbl='tbl_jurusan';
    $isi = $as->select($tbl,'*');
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($isi)){
    echo"<option value=$r[id_jurusan]>$r[jurusan]</option>";
    }
    echo"</select><br />        

    Tipe Kelas<br>
    <select name='tipekelas'>
    <option value ='0'>pilih tipe kelas..</option>";
    $tbl='tbl_tipe_kelas';
    $isi = $as->select($tbl,'*');
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($isi)){
    echo"<option value=$r[id_tipe_kelas]>$r[tipe_kelas]</option>";
    }
    echo"</select><br />        

    Golongan Darah<br>
    <select name='goldar'>
    <option value ='0'>pilih golongan darah..</option>";
    $tbl='tbl_goldar';
    $isi = $as->select($tbl,'*');
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($isi)){
    echo"<option value=$r[id_goldar]>$r[nama_goldar]</option>";
    }
    echo"</select><br />

    Alamat<br />
    <textarea name='alamat'></textarea><br />
    Kode Pos <br /><input type='text' name='kodepos' class='text' /><br />
    Kontak <br /><input type='text' name='kontak' class='text' required/><br />
    Email <br /><input type='text' name='email' class='text' /><br />
    Foto <br /><input type='file' name='gambar' class='text'/><br /><br>
    <div style='width:500px; margin-top:-10px;'><input class='graybutton' type='submit' value='Tambahkan'> &nbsp; <input class='graybutton' type='reset' value='Ulangi'></div>
</form>";
```

Comment: you want to store the image in mysql? or the image path in to the mysql, and the image in some directory.

Comment: i want store image in directory, and insert image path in mysql

Comment: What is it exactly that doesn't work? Did the query fails? Or perhaps the image didn't get moved to the designated upload directory? Please provide more details

Comment: also this has nothing to do with oop.

Comment: @KemalFadillah query without image is work, but with image isnt work

Comment: @Dan you mean, image upload can't works with oop? im not sure

Comment: @KemalFadillah i have checked the directory and is correct

Comment: @GalihPratama perhaps there was an error while uploading the file. Have you checked the value of `$_FILES['gambar']['error']` yet? Is it equal to 0?

Comment: @KemalFadillah i don't checked but images was uploaded. now the problem is image name isn't inserted into database (blank)

Comment: @GalihPratama You need to enclose the value of `$namafile` with quotes. Simply change `".$namafile."` to `'".$namafile."'`.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you have:

```
Foto <br /><input type='file' name='gambar' class='text'/><br /><br>
```

But in your PHP you have:

```
$file = $_POST['gambar'];
```

Perhaps I'm missing what you are doing, but surely it should be:

```
$file = $_FILES['gambar'];
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: thanks upload image is works, now the problem is image name isn't inserted into database :D

Answer (score 0):

Galih, we've all been noob. But please give us more detail of your problems, instead of "it doesn't work and you're stuck".

Yes, from your codes, the answer from Ralfe is one of the possibilities, and the comment from Kemal Fadillah about query fails is the other one.

From me, if you are doing image upload to the server, make sure the server's directory is writable by the application e.g the PHP.

And be aware from SQL injection since you insert the user's input to MySQL server without any filtering.

Comment: i have updated a question. about sql injection, i want add that later if all of my codes are finished.